# Geocoder returning incorrect coordinates for a specific location

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I've gone through all the possible threads that have tried addressing this question and none have given a definitive answer on what the correct solution is.

Can someone tell me how I could resolve the issue of a geocoder giving incorrect coordinates.

For example: For London, geocoder returns the following coordinates: 0.4200255,51.8786707.

I verified this on google maps and found that its on the coast of somalia which is obviously incorrect.

I did think about using a reverse geocoder which would mean i could provide the correct coordinates and it should return the correct location, but apparently it doesnt work either.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I could do to solve the problem?

Thanks in Advance!

```
for(String s: keys) {
      x = gc.getFromLocationName(s, 1);
}
```

s is a set of string locations which is iterated using foreach loop.

Comment: Could you share a piece of your code with us? That will help us understand what you have tried and might see where the issue arises.

Comment: @RaymonddelaCroix Hi, I've added code that is relevant to this problem.

Comment: What is `s` value?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Hi, sorry I should have explained. s contains the location such as "London", x is an Address List: List<Address> which holds the coordinate value

Comment: I understand but I need to know what it is **precisely** and what is `x` once call returns

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Hi, the variable s contains the location value which is found in "key" which is a set of strings. The purpose of s, is to include a print statement to verify the locations stored in variable "Key". As for "x" it is simply a list, that returns coordinates for a given location produced by the geocoder

Comment: Maybe try increasing the number of results and see if any of it matches? Maybe the priority is messed up. Also if you can share more code it would be useful, right now there is little context.